# yahoo connectivity with java code

Tags: java

I want to develop a yahoo client (core java) which connects to yahoo messenger ,checks for the authentication and login through java code.

I have already used jymsg api ,but since yahoo changed its protocol after august 15,2009 i m not able to connect to yahoo  server through java code.Is there any api or source available?Do i need to change the authentication method.help in this 2 resolve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Yahooo Instant Messaging API](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/openymsg) for you.

Comment: Thanks dear,I even tried using open ymsg ,even then i m  not able to connect to yahoo server through java code.